# Where is everybody?

Tags: discussion, badges

While poking through the [badge listings](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/badges), I noticed that only 24 people have been awarded the [Precognitive badge](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/badges/66/precognitive), which is awarded for following the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts) before it entered beta.

So herein lies my uncertainty: we have 139<sup>1</sup> users, 217 people committed to the beta, but only 24 have been awarded the badge.
Have only 11% of the beta committers actually visited and logged in? If so where did the rest of the members come from (maybe from a private beta invite)? Or are my figures totally out of whack?

<sup>1</sup> Including the ♦ mods who are possibly only observing, and not counting Community

Comment: The Precognitive badge is awarded to users who followed the Area 51 proposal *before it entered the commitment phase.* The commitment phase for Martial Arts started 11 months ago. Only users who followed the proposal before then can be awarded the badge. This will be a lower number than the total number of users who followed the A51 proposal before it entered beta; many, like me, will have followed *during* the commitment phase.

Comment: Thanks @Nick that explains it. You should make that an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Precognitive badge is awarded to users who followed the Area 51 proposal *before it entered the commitment phase.* The commitment phase for Martial Arts started 11 months ago. Only users who followed the proposal before then can be awarded the badge. This will be a lower number than the total number of users who followed the A51 proposal before it entered beta; many, like me, will have followed *during* the commitment phase.

As to why 141 of the 217 committed users have made an appearance so far:

- Private beta only started 5 days ago.
- People have busy lives. :)
- Not everyone who committed will follow through.

I think the [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts) show it's an encouraging start; opening the beta should build traffic and users further.

Comment: and now we are public!